# Javascript Error catch range value

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem with javascript..

The function like this..

```
<script>
            function validasi(){
                var x=document.forms["form1"]["request"].value;
                var y=document.forms["form1"]["stock"].value;
                if (x>y)
                  {
                  alert("Stock available only "+ y +"");
                  return false;
                  }
            }
</script>
```

and The form like this..

```
<form name="form1" id="form1">
Request :<input type="text" name="request" id="request">
</br>
Stock : <input type="text" name="stock" id="stock" value="100">
</br>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="validasi()">
</form>
```

Why when i fill the request = 90 and stock = 150. the alert show.. 
But when I fill the request = 10 and stock = 150. the alert not show..

Anyone can help me.. Thanks for the attention..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the values :

```
var x=parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["request"].value);
```

Right now you're comparing strings and for example `"9" > "150"` is `true`.

Note also that it would be better to directly use the id you have :

```
var x=parseFloat(document.getElementById("request").value);
```