# Simple subtraction function isn't working correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to be able to allow a user to input the amount of points they want to share. When they hit share, the points should should subtract from the points you have available (500 points). You should be able to continue to share until the amount you input is greater than the points you have. For some odd reason, my problem exists in the fact that certain numbers that you use break it such as the number 23 or 83. Try it yourself and provide any feedback for fixing this problem.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justinw001/vbLtu/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="points" readonly></input>
<input type="text" id="points-to-share" placeholder="Share Points"></input>
<button>Share</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
//Set default value of input
var availablePoints = $('#points').val(500);
$(availablePoints);

// Substracts value from remaining points
$('button').click(function() {

    var availablePoints = $('#points').val();
    var sharingPoints = $('#points-to-share').val();

    if (sharingPoints > availablePoints) {
        alert('Not enough Points');
    }
    else {
        var pointsLeft = availablePoints - sharingPoints;
        $('#points').val(pointsLeft);
    }

});
```

Comment: Use parseFloat to convert those strings to numbers

Comment: possible duplicate of [get wrong result function jquery javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925288/get-wrong-result-function-jquery-javascript)

Comment: @dystroy: The subtraction operator converts the values to numbers automatically.

Comment: @FelixKling There's a comparison before that and "2">"10"

Comment: @dystroy: Uh, yeah....

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with subtraction? The problem is obviously in `if (sharingPoints > availablePoints)`

Comment: FWIW, you can replace `var availablePoints = $('#points').val(500); $(availablePoints);` with just `$('#points').val(500);`. You are not using `availablePoints` anywhere else (in that scope) and `$(availablePoints);` on its own does nothing.

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631354/javascript-error-catch-range-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are comparing strings.

Change your code to this:

```
$('button').click(function() {

    var availablePoints = $('#points').val();
    var sharingPoints = $('#points-to-share').val();

    if (Number(sharingPoints) > Number(availablePoints)) {
        alert('Not enough Points');
    }
    else {
        var pointsLeft = availablePoints - sharingPoints;
        $('#points').val(pointsLeft);
    }

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbLtu/2/)

As pointed by @p.s.w.g. , its a good idea to parse your inputs in the begining, so you will not have to worry in the rest of the function.

```
$('button').click(function() {

    var availablePoints = Number($('#points').val());
    var sharingPoints = Number($('#points-to-share').val());

    if (sharingPoints > availablePoints) {
        alert('Not enough Points');
    }
    else {
        var pointsLeft = availablePoints - sharingPoints;
        $('#points').val(pointsLeft);
    }

});
```

Comment: Couldn't you let this question be closed as duplicate ?

Comment: @dystroy In my humble opinion, while both questions has the same problem, the other one is way more confusing than this one, starting by the question title.

Comment: it is probably more useful to do `var availablePoints = Number($('#points').val());`, etc. That way any use of the values elsewhere (such as in the subtraction or if OP later puts some addition in there too) they will be treated as numbers without the need for any other conversions.

Comment: That is most definitely true. Thanks for clarifying that :).

Comment: @p.s.w.g Sure! I edited the answer to include your suggestion. Thanks!